# Django staticgenerator vs CACHE_BACKEND

Tags: django, django-cache

Is there any difference between [staticgenerator](https://github.com/luckythetourist/staticgenerator) and useing Django's [CACHE_BACKEND on the filesystem](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/cache/#filesystem-caching) eg. CACHE_BACKEND = 'file:///var/tmp/django_cache' ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

`StaticGenerator` generates static HTML files to **bypass Django entirely**.

Any caching that django does such as the filesystem cache is still processed by django. A lot of the overhead of running your app is still there: django processes a request, goes through middlewares, checks filesystem cache for content, etc.

With StaticGenerator (and their example), `nginx` is serving the `index.html` page if it exists and if it doesn't, passes the request on to django on apache.

The idea is to have `nginx` blissfully serving some html file that `StaticGenerator` updates  on state changes (like saving a model).